# Protobufjs creating Types using reflection but missing type information

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, protobufjs

Not using TS only JSDoc.
I am trying to use Protobufjs with the Reflection only mode.

When using new protobuf.Type:

```js
const VectorData = new Type("VectorData")
    .add(new Field("x", 1, "float"))
    .add(new Field("y", 2, "float"))
    .add(new Field("z", 3, "float"));
```

the only type information I get is `protobuf.Type` which doesnt really help since my Fields are missing? Is there any way I need to write my own type def, because in TS I could just use decorators.

```js
export class VectorData extends Message<VectorData> {
    @Field.d(1, "float")
    public x: number;

    @Field.d(2, "float")
    public y: number;

    @Field.d(3, "float")
    public z: number;
}
```

Is there any better way to do this in JSDoc?